# Custom Properties file in Spring is not loaded to target folder on build

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, pom.xml, properties-file

I have a custom property file called test.properties present in the classpath folder. I am loading the file in the main class using @PropertySource as below,

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "packageName")
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:test.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
@EnableScheduling
@EntityScan(
        basePackageClasses = {Application.class}
)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {}
```

All the files included in the classpath folder are being added to the target folder, except for this.

Hence, it is throwing a FileNotFound exception. The properties file is not excluded anywhere in the project.

I'm unable to find what the issue here is. Any help or links to the solution will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried giving it another name? Might be some magic because it is called test...

Comment: @grekier yes the same issue, the project is being built by others, is there any chance that it is being excluded in the build path or somewhere else?

Comment: When you say classpath folder do you mean the resources folder?

Comment: @johnnyutts yes resources folder

Comment: Maybe you pressed some wrong button in your IDE? Is is possible that you explicitly excluded this file for packaging?